# CopyOnWriteArrayList is too slow

Tags: java, performance, thread-safety, copyonwritearraylist

I have following case,

```
public class Test {

    private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 10_00_00;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER; i++) {
            list.add(i * 2);
        } 
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(((end - start) / Math.pow(10, 9)));
    }

}
```

***OUTPUT***

```
6.861539857
```

It adds element quite *slowly* compared to `ArrayList` which took approximately `0.004690843`. I came to know the reason in the documentation,

> A thread-safe variant of `ArrayList` in which all mutative operations
>   (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the
>   underlying array.

So, my understanding is, whenever I add new element in this list it will create new fresh array and add element at last index of this array. I find a lock in `add` method and apart from that that method is actually creating new array every time.

When I increased `MAX_NUMBER` to `10_00_000` my programs keeps on running and never end (*it would but I can't wait for so long*).

I think `Collections.synchronizedList` is the better choice when you want thread safety with speed. I used it and it took about `0.007673728`.

My questions :

1. Why internally it create new array does thread safety is related to this ?
2. Why it took so much time in case of `MAX_NUMBER = 10_00_000` ? (as it took about 6 seconds with `MAX_NUMBER = 10_00_00`) Is this happening because mutative operation creates new array every time ?
3. Does this mean `CopyOnWriteArrayList` has performance drawback when you have huge number of elements and better to choose something else (i.e. `Collections.synchronizedList`)?
4. Is this the reason we usually don't see `CopyOnWriteArrayList` in public APIs ? Is there any drawbacks other than this ?

Comment: Javadoc: _This is ordinarily too costly, but may be more efficient than alternatives when traversal operations vastly outnumber mutations, and is useful when you cannot or don't want to synchronize traversals, yet need to preclude interference among concurrent threads_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` is the preferred option ONLY WHEN there are very less number of writes and huge number of reads (if multiple threads are accessing this list)